# Método finally en promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Típicamente este es un ejemplo sencillo de una *Promise* en JavaScript

```
let app = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let numero = 2
  resultado = (numero % 2 === 0) ? true : false
  resolve(resultado)
  reject(0)
})
```

La cual a través de la variable `app` accedemos a lo que procesa y nos puede devolver

```
app.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Donde identificamos lo siguiente

- `then` retorna el resultado cuando la promise se resuelve correctamente
- `catch` procesa el posible error que enfrente la promise y por el cual no sea capaz de devolver un resultado exitoso

Sin embargo investigando aquí [finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/finally) encuentro que puedes encadenar otro método llamado `finally` el cual según la misma fuente sirve para y cito:

> Devuelve una `promise` cuando esta se resuelve, sea exitosa o rechazada

Entonces genero este ejemplo

```
let app = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let numero = 2
  resultado = (numero % 21 === 0) ? true : fadlse
  resolve(resultado)
  reject(0)
})

app.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
}).finally(() => {
  console.log("Procesada con exito o fallos")
})
```

El cual por supuesto al tener `fadlse` me dará este error

> [object Error] { ... }

Pero el método `finally` se procesa de acuerdo a la definición citada y me retorna esto

> "Procesada con exito o fallos"

Aclaro NO busco opiniones, pero dado que `finally` retorna algo independiente de que la *promise* sea o no resuelta, ¿cuál es uso práctico de este método?

Comment: La clausula `finally` es común en muchos lenguajes ... _PHP_, _Java_, el propio _JavaScript_ ... hasta *C++* tiene su versión (llamada RAII). Pues lo mismo, pero adaptado a *promises* :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las secciones *finally* generalmente se utilizan para realizar alguna tarea que debe ejecutarse independientemente de si se presentan errores o no, dentro de un proceso.

La idea más simple que se me ocurre, es que se tenga algún tipo de indicador visual, que va a mostrarse solamente mientras se resuelve el Promise. Este indicador visual debe quitarse **siempre**, independientemente de si hubo algún error o no o de cuál es el resultado del promise.

Algo como:

```
let app = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //el código de mi Promise
})

mostrarIndicadorVisual();    
app.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
}).finally(() => {
  quitarIndicadorVisual();
})
```

Otro uso típico de finally es la liberación de recursos del sistema. Hablamos por ejemplo de memoria, sockets u otros recursos que suelen ser limitados. Al dejar la liberación de recursos dentro de **finally**, se garantiza que esta ocurra independientemente de lo que haya pasado dentro del Promise y con lo mismo una ejecución eficiente, en cuanto al uso de recursos, de nuestros programas.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta